# Is there anyone know how to steam idlers work?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api, steambot

Just wondering. I searched and couldn't find anything about that. Freehourbooster, steamtimeidler or something like that.

how does it work? With APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I just recently made an incredibly simple idler myself using the [Steamworks API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk). Just calling `SteamAPI_Init` with a text file`steam_appid.txt` containing the game's app ID in the same folder as the executable will tell Steam the game is running. Make sure to call `SteamAPI_Shutdown` when you close the application as well, and that's pretty much all that's needed for a simple idler